# sample example about Dependency injection needs explanation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I was going through this article about dependency injection http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

It shows Unity Container from Microsoft.

There are a few things that are not making sense to me

for example, following line

```
  public ProductsController(IProductRepository repository)
```

The above is the constructor of Controller. I need to know who passes the `repository` to the constructor? ANd is that made possible by registering  IProductRepository interface with Unity?

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
 {
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

// Other Web API configuration not shown.
}
```

Is the above code is all needed to make MVC pass the object to the constructor of a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question:

*is that made possible by registering IProductRepository interface with Unity?*

Yes.

When you request to resolve a type using Unity, the container searches for public constructors. If the constructor needs some implementation (`IProductRepository` in your case), the container searches within its registrations for an implementation for all the needed parameters. If found, it resolves that.  This is a recursive process.

So yes. You need to register an implementation of `IProductRepository` using the container in order to resolve an instance of the Controller using that container.

Comment: One addition: The OP says *Is the above code is all needed to make MVC pass the object to the constructor of a controller?* It is not MVC that passes the object but unity. MVC asks unity for the controller because the default DependencyResolver is overwritten with a Unity specific implementation.